# Disabling evil-mode for Nav in Emacs? Or any read-only buffers?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm trying to get something like Nerd Tree in Emacs and found Nav, which is like the basic emacs file navigator, and it suits me.

The problem is, when I open Nav and switch to its buffer, evil-mode is still on and I have to press `C-z` if I want to use any Nav specific commands (e.g. `.` for `nav-toggle-hidden-files`). And it annoys me.

It's been a few hours I'm trying to fix that issue, by pasting

```
(require 'evil)
    (evil-mode 0)
```

everywhere in the Nav files, but obviously I'm doing it wrong..
And I'm pretty sure it will happen again while using other plugins..
How do I do that?

Comment: +1 on the question.  This is one of the reasons my transition from vim-> emacs+evil has been so rocky... is just getting acclimated to a new projects directory structure before i have it memorized with helm/ido.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `nav-mode` buffers to open in Emacs state rather than in Evil's normal state.  I don't know what `nav-mode` is actually called, but do the following, adjusting the name of the mode accordingly:

`(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'nav-mode)`

Comment: Glad to help.  Incidentally, take a look at this thread for some additional options alongside `nav-mode`: http://superuser.com/questions/695256/file-management-in-emacs

Comment: Nice! I'll take a look cause of course it bugs me a little bit to leave the evil-mode while navigating through files :P I'm such a princess when it comes to my editor haha

Comment: Here's an example to do it for many modes in the same time: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil#Enter_an_emacs_mode_in_a_given_state

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've been searching for ages! I was about to advice a bunch of functions :D

Answer (score 12):

As described on the evil wiki [here](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Evil#Enter_an_emacs_mode_in_a_given_state) you might want to check out evil-set-initial-state.

Here's the relevant part of my emacs config:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'ibuffer-mode 'normal)
(evil-set-initial-state 'bookmark-bmenu-mode 'normal)
(evil-set-initial-state 'dired-mode 'emacs)
(evil-set-initial-state 'sunrise-mode 'emacs)
```

Doesn't alleviate the fact that I sure would like to have vim key bindings in these modes someday however...

Answer (score 7):

What you need is "hook", which will tell Emacs under which conditions you want a particular mode to be active or not.

I don't use `evil` or `nav` modes, but you want something very *similar* to the following line in your `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'nav-mode-hook 'turn-off-evil-mode)
```

This command tells Emacs that when the mode (whose hooks are listed in `nav-mode-hook`) is active, run the function `turn-off-evil-mode`.  You will likely have to modify either the hook list name, or the callback function name according to how `nav-mode` and `evil-mode` are implemented.

`nav-mode-hook` is my guess at what `nav-mode` will call its hook list.  If it doesn't work, check the `nav-mode` documentation, look for how to add hooks.

Comment: Thanks for your information, it certainly helped me understand how emacs functions a little bit more.

Comment: The correct command to run is `turn-off-evil-mode`.